# mkCert not installing on windows 10

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, mkcert

I seem to be doing everything right following this document

https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

to install `mkcert` on windows via `chocolatey`.

Also, I get a message that it gets installed successfully. But then the next moment when I try running mkcert, it gives an error that `mkcert` is not recognized.

I tried installing/uninstalling choco in this process a several times without any luck.

[image]

Also, in case this is relevant this is how the `mkcert` folder looks like after installing from `choco`

[image]

The `tools` folder remains empty though.